# How to do like this? Photoshop effects

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, effects

I want to know what is the name of the effect that made the man half hidden(like low opacity, shadow or some thing.)
If someone know what it is , please give its name or tell how to do this, please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd most likely call it a vignette.  A vignette is a border around a photograph which fades out into the background. In your example the background is white.

There are several ways to achieve it, such as using a layer mask and painting on the mask with a soft edged brush, or making a feathered selection then inverting it and filling it. Another possibility is using a large soft edged brush with the eraser tool on the image layer itself. Although if you want to keep it non-destructive, use a layer mask to achieve it.

Here's an example below. The background of this photograph has been masked out by selecting the figure with the Quick Selection tool, then I refined the mask using the Select and Mask functionality.

Then I painted on the mask in black, with a large soft edged brush on the parts where I want the image to fade out to the background.

[image]

Comment: Thanks  lot.  Soon i will search for google and find a video tutorial.